# Memory Address Range - F7FFF000 converted to what command line option?

Tags: explorer

First, appreciate you giving this a look. I have an ancient piece of software that writes old Linear PCMCIA cards. In my case, I want to use it in a specialized piece of gear called a Tech2. The software in question is called Memory Card Explorer. Now, I know for a fact it works in Windows XP with Native PCMCIA slots. However, I have a slot that is built on a Dual Systems adapter (basically an Expresscard to PCMCIA adapter).

The issue arises when following the instructions on installation issues, the program refuses to locate the Dual Adapter. Here's the example given in the manual:

"Use a similar address to the PCMCIA adapter. That address can be found using msinfo32.exe.

Eg: if the PCMCIA socket has a memory resource of F8000000 then use a MCE window command of F80D0000 using command line option of WF80D0."

So I get my adapter address which is F7FFF000 but have no idea where to add the "d" to the resource address then change it to a command. I've tried WF7FD0. Am I missing something simple in how these addresses are truncated for command line? Is there a calculator that does the conversion for you somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: No luck. As a response it says F7FFF000 (=WF7FFF) but I did add the "W" in front of the command.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the pattern is to add `0x000D0000` to the address, take the five high nibbles of the address (which makes sense, since these sorts of addresses are typically page-aligned the bottom 3 nibbles will always be 0 on a system with 4KiB pages), and prepend 'W'. Try `WF80CF`.

Comment: The application launches but doesn't detect the card. The memory ranges are F7FFE000 - F7FFEFFF, F4000000 - F5FFFFFF, F6000000 - F6FFFFFFF. It says Generic CardBus Controller. Would WF60CF work?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no specific knowledge about this device/software. I'm just extrapolating from the information you've given.

Comment: OK- Thanks for giving it a go! Appreciate it.